# Why is primefaces Fileupload not Visible?

Tags: firefox, jsf-2, opera, primefaces, fedora-core

The fileupload Control for  is not visible in the browser(rendered though).

When I viewed the source code from the browser, it was rendered like this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {widget_exeupload1 = new PrimeFaces.widget.Uploader('exeupload1', {uploader:'/jsfscrb/javax.faces.resource/fileupload/uploadify.swf.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2.1',script:'/jsfscrb/home.xhtml',cancelImg:'/jsfscrb/javax.faces.resource/fileupload/cancel.png.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2.1',formId:'j_idt225',fileDataName:'exeupload1_file',multi:false,auto:true,inputFileId:'exeupload1_file',jsessionid:'f99f510153df31f57a310fb8de8e',update:'dlist1 resmsg',fileDesc:'Resource Files'});});
</script>
```

I use the Fedora Core 3, NetBeans 6.8, Mojarra 2.0.4 with glassfish server v3. Above said behavior was observed with Firefox 2.0.0.20 and  also with Opera 10.11.

I am wondering where might the problem be and honestly couldn't guess it. Every little help to identify and/or solve the problem is very welcome please!!!

Where could the problem be?

- FedoraCore 3 graphic packages
- Primefaces
- Firefox or Opera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrimeFaces 2.2.x fileupload uses flash so depending on flash plugin, it might have issues. Try 3.0's new fileupload which uses HTML5 with graceful degradation. No flash is required with 3.0.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml

Comment: Isn't PrimeFaces 3.0 still in development ?

Comment: HTML 5 means i need to use some advanced browser than FF 2.0.0.20 or Opera 10.51 right? Those versions are the highest possible versions I could install in Fedora 3. Must I upgrade the browser inorder to get the `<p:fileUpload/>` working? Is there no other way?

Comment: For all other Primefaces Components I want to use Primefaces 2.2.1 and For the FileUpload Component alone I want to use primefaces 3.0 SNAPSHOT, inside the same JSF page. Is it possible?