# Primefaces 2.2.1 with FileUpload from Primefaces 3.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, file-upload

Related to the last comment on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190744/why-is-primefaces-fileupload-not-visible), i would like to know if anyone managed to use the HTML5-Fileupload of Primefaces 3.0 with an older Primefaces version.

We have a lot of trouble with the old flash-version of the fileupload.
I know that the best option would be to update the whole project to the new primefaces version but it´s not possible for this project.

Comment: try to add `immediate="true"` to your submit button

Comment: immediate="true" is reducing the lifecycle so that you can't upload a file. The uploadedFile in the fileBean will be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to be trivial. That you're already asking this question already indicates that it's going to be a long journey. I'd rather use a barebones and to-the-point file upload component of another component library such as Tomahawk's `<t:inputFileUpload>`. It only doesn't support asynchronous uploading and you need to make the submit button of the form a non-ajax one, but it does the job you want it to do without much hassle.

You can find in this answer detailed step-by-step instructions how to integrate and use it in your project: [JSF 2.0 File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418292/jsf-2-0-file-upload/5424229#5424229). In case of PrimeFaces, you only need to make sure that you have *removed* PrimeFaces' own file upload filter from the `web.xml`, otherwise it would consume the uploaded file before Tomahawk's own filter get the chance.

Comment: Thanks for your anser. I tried to integrate the tomahawk fileupload. The only problem i have is that i have a form with <h:inputText>-tags which are required. If i try to upload a file the required-tags are not filled and the form is (of course) not submitted. I tried to use the tomahawk subform but there is the same error. I will update the question with the current code. Maybe you have a solution for me.

Comment: Please do not reuse already answered questions for completely different questions/problems. Press `Ask Question` button instead.

Comment: Sorry, i reverted my edit of the question and posted a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101853/tomahawk-inputfileupload-in-subform-required-fields-are-validated)

Answer (score 0):

Thats very difficult, I have many problems with fileupload and finally migate to 3.0 but witch are problems?.

If you wanna to change fileupload you will can change source code in library is not very smarted if you desnt know jquery ui o you can use other framework or use directly.

http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/

good luck