# Tomahawk inputFileUpload in subform: required fields are validated

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, tomahawk

I have integrated the inputFileUpload of Tomahawk in my webapplication. I have tried to use it with subform from tomahawk but with no luck.

My form looks like this:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <!-- some <h:inputText required="true" /> tags -->

   <t:subform id="testSubForm">
       <t:inputFileUpload value="#{fileBean.uploadedFile}" />

       <t:commandButton action="#{fileBean.submit()}" value="Submit subForm"/>
   </t:subform>
</h:form
```

The problem is that the submit of the subform tries to validate the inputText-tags which are required but not filled.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can't you separate them into 2 different forms?

Comment: i do not see where validation is done in your subform, can you elaborate on that point?

Comment: Separating in two forms would be the last option for me and if i understand the subform docs correct my case should work fine.

With validation i mean the validation of required input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting my form in two forms works fine now.